# Chatbot using RASA with Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to learn and create a chatbot using RASA which has to pass inputs from cmdline to a Python Dataframe exposed as Flask API and get the response back.

All bits and pieces are working well separately but when I stitch together I am not able to pass the input parameter to the Pandas from RASA cmdline.

Here is the overall summary of **what I have done so far** :

- Created a Panda Dataframe and exposed it as a Flask API.
- Able to hit it manually and see the output in browser.
- Modified the Flask API route as "@app.route("/webhook")" to collect input from RASA.
- RASA endpoint.yml also contains "webhook" address.
- Created a custom action and mentioned it domain.yml file as well. contents of the custom action - actions.py are mentioned below.
- Domain.yml also has this statement "action_factory: remote" which I believe is to leverage the custom action. Not sure though.

> ```
> class ActionBookSearch(Action):
> def name(self):
>   return 'action_genre_search'
>
> def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
>   import pyflask_api ### File name of the Python Flask code
>   genre_val = tracker.get_slot('genre') ### Defined slots in domain.yml
>   print(genre_val)   ### This always gives None :( That's the issue. Not able to get the value from cmdline
>   genre_results = pyflask_api.get_genre(genre="Action") ### Method present in pyflask_api.py code
>   if genre_results:
>       dispatcher.utter_message(genre_results)
>   return [SlotSet("genre", genre_results if genre_results is not None else "Nothing Matched. Please Try again")]
> ```

**Work Around :**

Since I was not able to get the value from the Bot cmdline, I hard-coded in the below line for checking :

> genre_results = pyflask_api.get_genre(genre="Action")

This value is going to the Flask code and extract data from Panda dataframe and brings the response back to the command line successfully.

**what needs to be done :**

So only thing pending is I should get the value successfully from cmdline so that whenever print(genre_val) gets executed in actions.py code it should return the value that it took from cmdline instead of "None" as it does now.

**UPDATE :**

contents of domain.yml :

```
entities:
    - genre

slots:
    genre:
        type: text

action_factory: remote

intents:
  - greet
  - book_search
  - thanks
  - goodbye

actions:
  - utter_greet
  - utter_goodbye
  - action_genre_search
  - utter_happy_reading
```

contents of stories.md :

```
#create your story here
## greet
* greet
- utter_greet

## get genre
* book_search{"genre": "Fantasy"}
- action_genre_search

## good bye
* goodbye
- utter_goodbye

## Thank you
* thanks
- utter_happy_reading
```

Contents of nlu_data.md :

```
## intent:greet
- hey
- hello

## intent:book_search
- I want to read some Fantasy books
- I want to read some Classics books
- I want to read some Fictional books

## intent:thanks
- perfect
- very good

## intent:goodbye
- bye
```

Comment: Hi JKC, How is the slot is being set? Are you using NLU for that purpose? If so can you please check if the Slot is being set properly ? Also can you please share your stories.md file?

Comment: @KarthikSunil I have included slots in the domain.yml file and referring them in stories.md but not sure whether it is properly set :( . may be you can help me out by referring to those contents which I have updated in the question

Comment: @JKC: `action_factory: remote` is not required. Adding `action_genre_search` to the `actions` section is enough. This seems like an entity extraction problem. Are you using NLU, how does the NLU training data look like, whats your pipeline configuration?

Comment: Hi @Tobias Yes I am using NLU and my NLU Training data has been added now in the question (at the end). Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You have to [annotate your NLU examples](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/dataformat/) e.g.:

```
## intent:book_search
 - I want to read some [Fantasy](genre) books
 - I want to read some [Classics](genre) books
 - I want to read some [Fictional](genre) books
```

Also you have to add more examples to make the entity extraction more robust.
To make this work make sure that the [ner_crf](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/components/#ner-crf) is in your NLU pipeline.